# Simple way to read one image from the JSON URL to HTML

Tags: javascript

Can someone please advise on a SIMPLEST way to show the email on HTML page from a JSON URL? I tried to run search, but everyone's advise is related to some complicated code that people have. I can read the data from the JSON URL, but I need to know how to instead of the url of the image show the image itself in my page.

JSON file has this location:

```
{"icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/icon.gif"}
```

if I use this JS format, It just reads the URL data into my HTML site.

```
document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = something.icon_url;
```

What would be the **simple** code, to have this gif actually show as picture on my test website?

Comment: Just to let you know why you've been down-voted (not me) You should try a quick google search before asking your question.

Comment: I did look through google almost all day, nobody explains it in a simple way that I could understand, it's all related to some complicated code, or they make JSON data example inisde JS and everything looks different... I know that someone, who considers this a basic thing, with years of experience would probably down vote my question... but we all have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to change the `innerHTML` attribute. Instead append an image with the DOM API.

```
//Assuming json_data is a variable containing the JSON in a string format.

json_data = JSON.parse(json_data);
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("image").appendChild(image);
}
image.src = json_data.icon_url;
```

Here's a quick snippet showing this functionality:

```js
//You will probably fetch this not set it manually.
json_data = '{"icon_url": "http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/581/296/c09.jpg"}';
json_data = JSON.parse(json_data);
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("image").appendChild(image);
}
image.src = json_data.icon_url;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="image"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if it isn't an `<img>` element that won't work, and by their example use of using `innerHTML` it isn't, as images don't have `innerHTML`

Comment: Oh, My bad. I'll change this to reflect that.

Comment: do i need to show the src in the HTML code? I just have this right now in HTML: 
<div id="image"> </div>

Comment: @Andrew I've just edited in a snippet with the correct code for you. Didn't know you had a div.

Comment: it's funny that I can read everything else from the JSON with just one line of code, while I need all this crazy code for one tiny gif. Is that because pictures are not HTML elements? Thank you so much, MustacheMan! :)

Comment: @Andrew pictures *are* HTML elements. They are simply img tags. Doing it from the JS side is bound to be a bit complicated due to how the DOM works.